# Build Error MSB3073:

Tags: visual-c++

I have an MFC application in VS2010. It also contains few project in C#.
during SVN build we get this error:

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(43,5): 
error MSB3073: The command "iscmdbld -p ..\..\..\testinstall.ism -r setup -o
..\..\thirdparty\installshield\mergemodules" exited with code 1.
```

We are using installshield 2010 for creating setup. We have same application in VS2005 also but there we don't get above mentioned error.
Please advise.